# HTTPS Request in QT C++ for iOS & Android

Tags: c++, ios, qt, ssl, twitter

I've been trying to find a way to integrate twitter to my cross platform qt project. 
What I want to achieve is nothing fancy. I just want to be able to use the Twitter API to fetch some tweets with a certain hashtag using app only credentials. 
In order to do that, I had to get a bearer token using their oauth2 authentication process. And according to their development page, SSL is required.
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

I've read that in QT, I can use QNetworkAccessManager to send QNetworkRequests but I can't seem to make it work. I get an error: "Protocol \"\" is unknown"

I've tried ready a lot of posts but I couldn't get what I want. I would appreciate all the help I could get to make this possible. If anyone can point me to the right direction/tutorial please do so:

Attached is my sample code:

.pro

```
QT += qml quick network
```

setup code:

```
m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(m_networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

request code:

```
QJsonObject params;
params.insert("grant_type","client_credentials");

QUrl url("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
url.setHost("api.twitter.com");

QNetworkRequest request;
QString authorizationKey =  m_consumerKey + ":" + m_consumerSecret;
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ authorizationKey.toUtf8().toBase64());
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
m_networkManager->post(request, QJsonDocument(params).toJson());
```

and finally my callback:

```
void NetworkClass::requestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    cout << "header size: " + reply->readBufferSize();
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        //success
        QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
        QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
        cout <<"result: " << response_data.toStdString();
    }
    else {
        //failure
        qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Note: I'm not very good with SSL and such. I'm still a new to this. Maybe that's why I feel so lost right now. Please please help me. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
@dutt pointed out that I forgot to set the url to the request. Yey! Finally I received a reply. However, I got this reply: 
*"Error transferring https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token - server replied: Forbidden"*

Comment: I might be missing something but...have you forgot to set the url for the request?

Comment: omg. I did forget. I added it. I finally received a reply:
"server replied: Forbidden"

Answer (score -1):

If You can use Qt 5.8, next may help: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/ and example https://github.com/qt/qtnetworkauth/tree/5.8/examples/oauth/twittertimeline 
(Not tested by me, but official example.)

Comment: Answers containing only links to external resources are discouraged at SO. You can improve your answer by explaining your suggestion in text with proper code examples.